# How to increase max bucket count in AWS elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, amazon-elb

I am using AWS elasticsearch and I want to increase the max-bucket count but the below query is not working

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "persistent": {
    "search.max_buckets": 20000
  }
}
```

And it is showing response as
`{"Message":"Your request: '/_cluster/settings' payload is not allowed."}`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

The cluster setting you'd like to change, like most other cluster settings, [is not currently exposed by Amazon Elasticsearch.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html) If your Elastic usage requires this or any other cluster setting that is not one of the following, you are out of luck and cannot use Amazon Elasticsearch.

Note that this is from the 7.x docs; the supported operations for other versions may vary:

- `action.auto_create_index`
- `action.search.shard_count.limit`
- `indices.breaker.fielddata.limit`
- `indices.breaker.request.limit`
- `indices.breaker.total.limit`
- `cluster.max_shards_per_node`

Answer (score 0):

No,we cannot change max bucket size .but you can setup a ES in server and use it for if need  more bucket size. But it will make the results slow